# ZF2 data table - configuring ZFTable

Tags: datatable, zend-framework2

I am looking at zfmodules to get a datatable module, and have found the perfect one :

https://github.com/dudapiotr/ZfTable

..however there is very little explanation of how to configure it into an existing project, change the data source etc.

Does anyone have any experience of this module, or is successfully using it in production?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I am searching for the same thing.

Comment: I have not used ZfTable, however for install did you try composer? And check out this post might save you some heart ache.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095925/zftable-module-zend-framework-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095925/zftable-module-zend-framework-2)

Comment: I didn't work with ZFTable, but I suggest see also https://github.com/mbrostami/zf2plugin-dataTable.

Comment: This seems helpful https://github.com/dudapiotr/ZfTable/wiki/Installation-and-Configuration

Comment: You did look at the examples, right?  http://dudapiotr.eu/table/additional-params

Answer (score 0):

> The thing that i understood from Question is " You want to inject this
>   Module in your current Application ", well i have checked the link [https://github.com/dudapiotr/ZfTable][1] and the module seems perfect to inject to your Application. *The only thing which seems unfitting is the 'data' folder, you should compile 
>   'customer.sql' onto your database, and then remove the folder 'data', since it does not matches to the framework structure

**Try these steps **
*

1. create your sql database exactly as mentioned in customer.sql
2. copy this module to your application, with other residing modules (if any).
3. Add the module name to **application.config.php** in *Application/config/autoload* directory ( since you are adding module manually, you must add your module name there by yourself)
4. And last, Routing configuration of your module in Application/config/module.config.php

> if you need any help in routing of step 4, go here [[Zend framework not able to route the translated child routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627013/zend-framework-not-able-to-route-the-translated-child-routes/41888502#41888502][1])

*