# Zend framework not able to route the translated child routes

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-translate, zend-framework3

I am new to Zend framework 3 and was trying to translate the routes and i have partially succeeded.I am able to translate the main route and redirect it to the required location but for child routes the translation works but the redirection doesn't. can you please help me, my code is below.

module.config.php

```
'router' => [
        'router_class'           => TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack::class,
        'routes' => [
            'setting' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/{locale}/{setting}',

                    'defaults' => [
                        'locale'     => 'de',
                        'controller' => Controller\SettingController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],

                'may_terminate'=>true,
                 'child_routes' =>[
                        'add' =>[
                            'type'      =>'Segment',
                            'options'   =>[
                                'route'         =>'/{add}',
                                'defaults'=> [
                                     'controller' => Controller\SettingController::class,
                                     'action'     => 'add',
                                ],
                            ],  
                        ],
                 ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Module.php

```
   public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $language_session = new Container('language');

        if(!$language_session->offsetExists('lang')){

           $language = 'de_DE';

        } else{

            $language = $language_session->lang.'_'.strtoupper($language_session->lang);
        }

        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $translator->setLocale($language); 
        $translator->addTranslationFile('phparray', __DIR__.'/language/'.$language.'.php', 'default',$language);

        $app      = $e->getTarget();
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('route', array($this, 'onPreRoute'), 100);
    }

    public function onPreRoute($e)
    {
        $app      = $e->getTarget();
        $serviceManager       = $app->getServiceManager();
        $serviceManager->get('router')->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
    }
```

And my language file de_De.php

```
return array(
    'locale'  => 'de',
    'setting' => 'Einstellung',
    'add'     => 'hinzufügen',
);
```

As per my above code i am able to redirect to Settings controller with the route "**language.devgrafioffshore.com/de/Einstellung**"

But not able to redirect to 
**language.devgrafioffshore.com/de/Einstellung/hinzufügen** which should redirect me to add action but i get

The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

Thank you in advance.
Bye!

Comment: According to documentation and what we can found on SO (some code are exactly the same), It seems OK. Did you found what was wrong since you post this question ?

Comment: @AlFonce yes i found one thing that "hinzufügen" doesn't work but "hinzufugen" works and if you have found a better way to solve the url translation than please let me know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> I have rewritten your code in zend framework2, take a look, i will try to expalin

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'setting' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/setting',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => '<<MODULE NAME HERE>>\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'SettingController',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'add' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/add[/:action[/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

            )

        ),
    ),
```

> The possible routes through this configuration are

***setting/add/anyActionName***

**setting/add/add**

***setting/add/test***

> The first add is not an action, rather it acts as a path to action. The second "add" or "anyActionName" are the actions you want to execute. A much better thing with this configuration is, that you can pass ID's also with action name through URL, but if you don't pass any ID, it's alright.
>
> One more very important thing, Configuration defined this way helps not to define every Action name because with

```
'constraints' => array(
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                        ),
```

> this constraint on action name, any Action name could passed, unless the Action Name contains any special character. If you have any questions regarding my solution, feel free to ask.